# Insert random video in place of actual filename

Tags: random, xbmc

I am looking for a way to modify the following script to play a random video in the folder /mnt/usb when script is ran.  Videos in the folder will change daily but will all be mov file type.  At the end of the video, it returns to our slideshow.

```
import xbmc
import time
import os

def PlayAndWait(mediafile):
  xbmc.executebuiltin("PlayMedia(%s)" % mediafile, True)
  while xbmc.Player().isPlaying():
    time.sleep(1.0)

if os.path.isfile ("/mnt/usb/videoenter.mov"):

        PlayAndWait("/mnt/usb/videoenter.mov")

xbmc.executebuiltin("SlideShow(/mnt/usb/slideshow)")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `glob.glob` to get the list of files matching `'/mnt/usb/*.mov'` then use `random.choice` to pick one out:

```
import xbmc
import time
import os
import glob
import random

def PlayAndWait(mediafile):
    # escape characters and quote if needed as xbmc requires
    if '"' in mediafile:
        mediafile = mediafile.replace('"','\\"')
    if any(x in mediafile for x in ",() "):
        mediafile = '"' + mediafile + '"'

    xbmc.executebuiltin("PlayMedia(%s)" % mediafile, True)
    while xbmc.Player().isPlaying():
        time.sleep(1.0)

files = glob.glob('/mnt/usb/*.mov')

if not files:

    filename = random.choice(files)

    if os.path.isfile(filename):

        PlayAndWait(filename)

xbmc.executebuiltin("SlideShow(/mnt/usb/slideshow)")
```

Comment: I am running script as shown above and am only getting the slideshow.  I have verified the video location and verified the mov format.  Has this script worked for you in the past?

Comment: @user3380826 I wrote it based on your script. I couldn't test it. Nor can I tell you why it isn't working for you. If your script worked, I would claim that mine would.

Comment: @user3380826 But perhaps you have some files with characters in their names that need to be escaped before being interpolated in `"PlayMedia(%s)" % mediafile` as http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Built-in_scripting states. Look at the file names perhaps you have a filename with a comma `,` or a quote `"` character in it. These need to be escaped.

Comment: @user3380826 I have updated the script to properly quote the filenames passed to xbmc.

Comment: I've just ran this script and it goes directly to the slideshow without playing a video.  I have a video in /mnt/usb/video0.mov which should play.